# When overwriting __init__ will I call __init__ of base class at the beginning or end?

Tags: python, oop, overriding

I have the following short example where I inherit a class `A` from `Base` and overwrite `__init__`. In the `__init__` the `Base.__init__` is called.

```
class A(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    super(A, self).__init__()
    ... my initialisation ...
```

**Is there a rule to call `__init__` of Base (when needed) first and then initialise the rest or should it be the other way round?**

Sometimes I need to call `__init__` and then do the rest and other times I need it the other way round. There are also occasions where I have to write some initialisation, then call `__init__` of the base class and then do some final initialisation.

Maybe giving an answer to myself: Read the documentation of the base class or if not available study the code.

**Is there a way it should be or how do you document this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no rule as to where to call it, or if you call it at all. Call it wherever it makes sense *to your specific situation*.

Put differently, `super(A, self).__init__()` is *just another method call*, albeit one that specifically uses a method looked up from a base class. Treat it like any other method call you make, so call it *when you need to*.